# Using Django Rest Framework as security layer for file system processing

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm trying to protect my remote server file system from unauthorized users.
I have a remote storage on a different server that store and process PDF's and PNG's from all kind of processes.

I'm using Python 2.7 with Django 1.8 and Django Rest Framework.

I trying to implement very basic, "Proxy Layer" that will give my control on who ever use file system.

This is my `view.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import permissions

import requests

class Reports(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)  #Thats only for now...

    def get(self, request, ssn, validity, file):
        response = requests.get(settings.PROXY_BASE_URL + "/reports/" + ssn + "/" + validity + "/" + file)
        return Response(response)
```

This concept works for any other `GET` `POST` `PUT` `DELETE` request that is text based response (For example json response from the remote server).

My problem is when I call this view, I get in the browser the default REST method definition page.

[This is the response screenshot](http://prntscr.com/9xz06z)

Comment: Gal, could you attach a link to a screenshot?

Comment: I attached it in the edit,

Comment: And if you append `?format=json` to your URL, does anything change?

Comment: Appending `?format=json` returns the image as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AlexMorozov said in his comment, you should revert back to `HttpResponse`.
You can see by exploring this [Django Snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1967/).

Here is the code as I see it:

```
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import permissions

from django.http import HttpResponse

import requests
import mimetypes


class Reports(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, ssn, validity, file):
        response = requests.get(settings.PROXY_BASE_URL + "/reports/" + ssn + "/" + validity + "/" + file)
        mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(settings.PROXY_BASE_URL + "/reports/" + ssn + "/" + validity + "/" + file) #Return an array
        return HttpResponse(response, content_type=mimetype[0])
```

Give it a go. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you can't simply wrap a `requests` response with a DRF `Response` and get it done. Change your code to:

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper

upstream_response = requests.get(settings.PROXY_BASE_URL + "/reports/" + ssn + "/" + validity + "/" + file)
response = Response(FileWrapper(upstream_response.content), content_type='YOUR_MIME_TYPE')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % 'your_filename.ext'
return response
```

BTW, there are other (more clean, IMO) ways to solve this particular task. Take a look at [django-sendfile](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile) app. It offloads the actual file serving to a nginx or the server of your choice, while allowing you to check permissions and stuff.

Comment: I'm getting `<wsgiref.util.FileWrapper instance at 0x0617F710> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Then it might be better to fall back to a plain Django `HttpResponse` instead of DRF's `Response`. Try if it helps, unfortunately, I don't have a playground to test it right now.