# Download a file using Django rest framework by authenticating the user

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working on a project where I am using Django as the back end. I am working with Django rest framework, and I have an API to download a File.

```
@detail_route(methods=['GET'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
def test(self, request, pk=None):
    try:
        ticket = Ticket.objects.get(id=pk, user=request.user)
        file_path = ticket.qrcode_file.path
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
                response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="image/jpeg")
                name = "%s %s %s %s.jpg" % (ticket.show.title, datetime.strftime(ticket.show.date_time,
                                                                                       "%H_%M_%p"),
                                            datetime.strftime(ticket.show.date_time, "%d %B %Y"), ticket.id)
                response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % name.replace(" ", "_")
                return response
        return Response({'error': 'Ticket doest not belong to requested user.'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    except Ticket.DoesNotExist as e:
        return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

On the front-end I am using Nuxtjs (ssr for vuejs). This is a little snippet of code, where a user can download the file by clicking a link of target blank.:

```
<a class="downloadBtn" target="_blank" :href="`${baseURL}/payments/api/tickets/${ticket.id}/download_ticket/`">Download e-ticket</a>
```

The web app is running on Nuxtjs server (localhost:3000) and Django server is running on localhost:8000, only the API is used to communicate between the Nuxtjs and Django by using the auth token.

When I click the download link it opens up a new tab and make a request from that new tab, where no token is passed with the request. And since, the django view to download the ticket is `permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]` I cannot be authenticated as `request.user` is anonymous.

Is there any other way that I can make it work to download the file by checking whether the requested user is the Ticket's owner?

Comment: does removing `target="_blank"` help ? I think the token is not being passed because the link is getting opened in a new tab, not sure though.

Comment: What kind of Authentication are you using Session or Token?

Comment: @ChintanJoshi Nope. Removing `target="_blank"` doesn't help.

Comment: @IgorYalovoy I am using Token authentication (jwt).

Answer (score 9):

Because you are using JWT, you should download the file from your **frontend** after requesting it from your **api** using some sort of `ajax request` and the JWT header.

```
some_api_request_hendler().then(function (response) {
    var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: response.headers("Content-Type")});
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdf);
    link.download = "the_new_file_name";
    link.click();
});
```

I'm using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42815974/5601726) as an example. Your API should not be changed. The way you did it is the way to go.

And your link now need to call your new frontend function instead of just `<a href`.

**Edit**:

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148650/using-django-rest-framework-as-security-layer-for-file-system-processing) like that a few years ago. You might find some help there.

**Browser Compatibility**

[blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Comment: Could you tell me about browser compatibility with this approach?

Comment: Worked for me in Chrome. Firefox usually doesn't like stuff like this unless it's triggered by a user. I suspect @Aamu you should be fine